# Objective-C "private" protocols?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, protocols

I got a view controller class (MyViewController) that deals with a UIView subclass (MyView). I don't want to let any class except the view controller class know about the UIView subclass, so I cannot import `MyView.h` in `MyViewController.h`.

So, in `MyViewController.m`, I put

```
#import "MyViewController.h"
#import "MyView.h"

@interface MyViewController (PrivateObjects)

MyView *myView;

@end

...
```

However, to get feedback from MyView, I use a delegate. That delegate has to implement the `MyViewDelegate` protocol.

How can I implement the `MyViewDelegate` protocol inside `MyViewController` without having to `#import` `MyView.h` in `MyViewController.h`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
@interface MyViewController (PrivateObjects) <MyViewDelegate>
....
```

(BTW, you can't declare a new ivar in a category.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a forware-declaration in MyViewController.h

```
@class MyView;

@interface MyViewController {
    MyView *myView;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it my sound strange, but by experience I can tell you to don't bother so much about privacy hierarchies in Cocoa.

So in an app or in internal frameworks simply document the class stating how it should used.

That's because you cannot have real privacy as long C pointers are around so Objective-C was designed with no syntax that would only give you some illusion of it.

For example the IB outlet variables of view controllers should typically only be accessible by the controller itself, but they are always public, because they must be accessible from the classes that unarchive and instantiate the nib files and link the outlets with the corresponding instances.

[including suggestions from bbum below]

Comment: It isn't that the language is inadequate in its support for private implementations, it is very much that the language is designed to *not* waste syntax on creating the illusion of privacy, which is all you'd have in a C based language anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Create a protocol (*.h) outside of MyView.h and use that in the declaration (*.h) of MyViewController, for example:

```
#import "MyViewDelegate.h"
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <MyViewDelegate>
```

--Frank

Comment: What if the delegate contains a method `- (void)myView:(MyView *)myView textDidChange:(NSString *)text`?

Answer (score -4):

Why do you even want to use a protocol? Just put the methods in your PrivateObjects category.

**Edit**: Apple refers to this technique as "[informal protocol](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Articles/ocProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-TPXREF147)"

Comment: Because "just putting the methods there" is bad programming style, plus `MyView` should be reusable, so a delegate is definitely useful here.

Comment: Aha, looks like I misunderstood "I don't want to let any class except the view controller class know about the UIView subclass"